# How are skip beats decided in Red River fiddling?

Tags: rhythm, violin, country-and-western

As I understand in [Red River fiddling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcPqo1X-EOM), the distinguishing feature of that style (as well as the more obscure James Bay and Athapaskan fiddling styles) is the skip beat.  That means a whole beat is dropped or inserted as the tune is played and that can mean clipping bits off of the melody or inserting bits of the melody.  But my knowledge of them only goes so far and I am left wondering the following question:

When do you insert the skip beat?  How is that decided?